# how to write one GET api call using axios instance with and without params in React JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios, frontend

I am new to React JS and Axios. I want to understand the best way of creating a GET instance using Axios that works with and without params. I am have developed a sample REST API call from React using axios.create({}) as below and it works fine.

```
import axios from 'axios';

const instance = axios.create({
    baseURL: 'example.com'
});

export default {
    getAllData: (url) =>
        instance({
            'method': 'GET',
            'url': url
        })
}
```

My requirement is to create axios GET instance that works with and without params and I could achieve it like below by creating 2 different functions:

```
export default {
        getAllData: (url) =>
            instance({
                'method': 'GET',
                'url': url
        }),
    
    getUser: (url, userId) =>
        instance({
                'method': 'GET',
                'url': url,
        'params' : userId
        })
    }
```

Is there any way to create one GET function that works with and without params using Axios in React JS?

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

```
getUser: (url, userId) =>
        instance({
                'method': 'GET',
                'url': url,
        ...(userId && {'params' : userId})
        })
```

If `userId` exists, it will append the `{'params': userId}` object to the current one.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to create 2 different methods. If you don't pass the `userId` parameter, it will be null and won't be passed to the API call.

You can use this code:

```js
import axios from 'axios';

// Set Global default
axios.defaults.baseURL = 'example.com';

const getData = (url, userId) => axios(url, userId);

export default getData;
```

You can call with `userId`:

```js
getData('/user', userId);
```

Or without:

```js
getData('/user');
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can do it:

```js
export default {
  getUser: (url, userId) =>
    instance.get(url, {
      ...(userId && {'params' : userId})
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
axios.get('/user?ID=12345')
  .then(function (response) {
    // handle success
    console.log(response);
  })
  .catch(function (error) {
    // handle error
    console.log(error);
  })
```